# Get current location and find the nearest station based on CSV with latitude and longitude

Tags: python, mysql, location, nearest-neighbor

We have an university assignment, where we have to make a python script, make a database if needed, to solve a task.

The task itself is that we have a CSV file with different stations with latitute and longtitude, and we need to find the closest one to the user.

We don't need to have a user interface, simple menu in python script will be enough.

I think about to just create python script with simple menu like.

1. Get info about the app.
2. Find the nearest location.

So, I need to find a way how to get a current user location who is running the script, and based on that provide him with the nearest station, using Haversine Distance Equation. I aslo got inspired by this article. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/finding-nearest-pair-of-latitude-and-longitude-match-using-python-ce50d62af546.

Any recommendations how to do that, or how to enhance the idea are more then weolcome!
The main point is to get the nearest station based on where you run the script.

I just got information about the problem rigth now, and we did some simple pythons crips, using CSV files in the past.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please always include some code. As is, it looks like you are asking us to do your work for you. Which is odd, since you seem to know what to do already. stackoverflow works best for specific questions about problems in your code, not open-ended and opinion-based discussions. See [ask].

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks, I'll create another question with some code later on then.

Comment: Don't create another one, [edit] this one. People tend to downvote you if you just post the same question again.